# How to make an input element less verbose in React?

Tags: reactjs

I wonder if there is a way to write a controlled input element in React that syncs State using useState.

Something like svelte does with value bindings.

Comment: Have you tried `<input value={state} onChange=(event => setState(event.target.value) />`?

Comment: The code to do this sync has to exist somewhere. With svelte, yes, its in the library. With react you need to do this binding yourself. But you can also just create your own common hooks and reuse them everywhere -- which has the same level of useability. In the end, it doesn't actually matter that much.

Comment: You might look at form libs like https://react-hook-form.com/ and https://github.com/esamattis/react-zorm. Lean on open source where you can. Effectively it gives you similar sort of binding behaviour.